# Paperclip Audio file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using paperclip gem to upload files. I want to upload different kinds of files like pdf, doc, video and audio. I have validation for file type in my model. For doc, pdf and Video it is working but it is not wroking for audio file. please help.
My model

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :avatar, :CategoryID
  has_attached_file :avatar
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['video/mp4','video/avi','Audio/mp3','application/pdf',"application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
             "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
             "application/msword", 
             "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
             "text/plain"]
  #validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['audio/mp3']
end
```

This is the error I got...

```
1 error prohibited this xyz from being saved:

    Avatar content type is invalid
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for any type of the file

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /.*/
```

You can also discover exact content type of the file with command

```
file -i path/to/file # or 
file --mime-type path/to/file
```

I have run in on MP3 file and it returned

```
audio/mpeg
```

So if you want to validate only some set of content types you can add 'audio/mpeg' to the list

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => [ ..., 'audio/mpeg', ...]
```