# How to upload an audio in rails application using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am uploading an audio file into my rails app and i am getting the following error

```
Avatar has contents that are not what they are reported to be
```

my model looks like this

```
    class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_attached_file :avatar
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['audio/mpeg','audio/mp3']
    end
```

my migration file look like this

```
    class AddAttachmentAvatarToPlaylists < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        change_table :playlists do |t|
          t.attachment :avatar
        end
      end

    def self.down
      remove_attachment :playlists, :avatar
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the actual content type of the file?

Comment: have you tried "application/mpeg", "application/mp3"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170182/paperclip-audio-file-upload